# can't access child node's value but i can access child node's name

Tags: javascript

when i try to access child nodes i can , but i can't access their value it says null

```
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","obj.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Objnode")[0].childNodes; 
    y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Objnode")[0].firstChild;    
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    if (y.nodeType==1)
      {//Process only element nodes (type 1)
      document.write(y.nodeName + "<br>"); change it to y.nodeValue it says null!
      }
    y=y.nextSibling;
    }
```

my xml is like

```
    <Objnode>
            <Object1>something</Object1>
            <Object2>something</Object2>
    </Objnode>
```

above code works but the line

```
document.write(y.nodeName + "<br>");
```

when changed it to y.nodeValue it says null!

Comment: Note that it's recommended to use a [library or framework](http://jquery.com) if you want to make AJAX calls.

Comment: i'll appreciate any try guys pls help me to learn

Comment: Rewrite with jQuery and you'll most likely not encounter this problem.

Comment: Please don't make synchronous XHR calls. They can hang up the browser and will definitely hang up the page rendering.

Comment: thank you jan for the advice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `nodeType 1` is an `HTML element, i.e. div, span etc` and an element doesn't has any `nodeValue` instead it could contain child nodes and remember that any text inside an `element` is also a node (text node). Look at this example

**HTML**

```
<div id="d">First Text Node <br /> Another Text Node</div>​
```

**JS**

```
var n=document.getElementById('d');
alert(n.firstChild.nodeValue);​ // First Text Node
alert(n.childNodes[2].nodeValue); // Another Text Node
```

So, in your example `y.nodeValue` is null.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/punUw/2/).